# How to display Json data using PHP?

Tags: php, json, algorithm, object, youtube-data-api

I have a json file and I want to display its data in a PHP file. I tried with the code below but its not work.

```
$json_output = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL3n6kxxrIGdat31ZIf_7wlqtT3I20OqLL?v=2&alt=jsonc");
$json = json_decode($json_output, true);


foreach($json->data->items->thumbnail as $day) {

   echo $day->sqDefault;
   echo $day->hqDefault;
}
```

and my json file is

```
{"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"id":"PL3n6kxxrIGdat31ZIf_7wlqtT3I20OqLL","author":"Tutorial top","title":"دورة سيو للمبتدئين [ali baba]","description":"","thumbnail":{"sqDefault":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XIhVZqCVqhs/default.jpg","hqDefault":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XIhVZqCVqhs/hqdefault.jpg"},"content":{"5":"http://www.youtube.com/p/PL3n6kxxrIGdat31ZIf_7wlqtT3I20OqLL"},"totalItems":31,"startIndex":1,"itemsPerPage":1,"items":[{"id":"PLH_kL5FgJPmdcYTGqaMXFsVJJ-pbR_YyiC1Y73R1tfYY","position":1,"author":"Tutorial top","video":{"id":"Kw8m5S2OhPs","uploaded":"2013-11-10T16:04:28.000Z","updated":"2014-02-18T17:59:36.000Z","uploader":"vkd-nAV91SLMCYNBKGJmsA","category":"People","title":"Beginners SEO Tutorial Course   Intro","description":"","thumbnail":
{"sqDefault":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Kw8m5S2OhPs/default.jpg","hqDefault":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Kw8m5S2OhPs/hqdefault.jpg"},"player":{"default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?
v=Kw8m5S2OhPs&feature=youtube_gdata_player","mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=Kw8m5S2OhPs"},"content":{"5":"https://www.youtube.com/v/Kw8m5S2OhPs?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata","1":"rtsp://r8---sn-4g57kues.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAn7hI4t5SYPKxMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp","6":"rtsp://r8---sn-
4g57kues.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAn7hI4t5SYPKxMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"},"duration":413,"aspectRatio":"widescreen","rating":5.0,"likeCount":"1","ratingCount":1,"viewCount":283,"favoriteCount":0,"commentCount":0,"accessControl":
{"comment":"allowed","commentVote":"allowed","videoRespond":"moderated","rate":"allowed","embed":"allowed","list":"allowed",
"autoPlay":"allowed","syndicate":"allowed"}}}]}}
```

I want the output like this

```
sqDefault  |   hqDefault

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Kw8m5S2OhPs/default.jpg,|https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Kw8m5S2OhPs/hqdefault.jpg
```

Comment: what type of  Output as you expected..tel me format

Comment: ok you can see the output above now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, if you'd like to access the JSON structure as an object (as opposed to an array) drop the second argument of `json_decode()`, otherwise you end up with an array as `$json`. Have a look at the [first example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#refsect1-function.json-decode-examples) to see the difference.
Then you should loop through the `items` array. Each of its elements has a `video` property, which has the `thumbnail`property you want

```
$json_output = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL3n6kxxrIGdat31ZIf_7wlqtT3I20OqLL?v=2&alt=jsonc");
$json = json_decode($json_output);
foreach ($json->data->items as $item) {
    echo $item->video->thumbnail->sqDefault;
    echo $item->video->thumbnail->hqDefault;
}
```

should do the job. You can [see it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vLojt4).

To get a clear picture of the structure one of the many online available JSON viewers could help you ;-)

Answer (score 4):

After many trials this is working fine.

I have tested in my local system.

Here is code:--

```
<?php
$json_output = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL3n6kxxrIGdat31ZIf_7wlqtT3I20OqLL?v=2&alt=jsonc");
$json = json_decode($json_output);
error_reporting(0);
foreach($json->data->thumbnail as $image) {
   echo $image.",|";
}

?>
```

**Output:-**

> https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XIhVZqCVqhs/default.jpg,|https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XIhVZqCVqhs/hqdefault.jpg

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

See that I remove the 2nd param in the `json_decode()` and I iterate with `$json->data->items[0]->video->thumbnail` and at the end I remove the final `|` with `rtrim()`

You can use this example:

```
<?php

$json_output = '{"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"id":"PL3n6kxxrIGdat31ZIf_7wlqtT3I20OqLL","author":"Tutorial top","title":"دورة سيو للمبتدئين [ali baba]","description":"","thumbnail":{"sqDefault":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XIhVZqCVqhs/default.jpg","hqDefault":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XIhVZqCVqhs/hqdefault.jpg"},"content":{"5":"http://www.youtube.com/p/PL3n6kxxrIGdat31ZIf_7wlqtT3I20OqLL"},"totalItems":31,"startIndex":1,"itemsPerPage":1,"items":[{"id":"PLH_kL5FgJPmdcYTGqaMXFsVJJ-pbR_YyiC1Y73R1tfYY","position":1,"author":"Tutorial top","video":{"id":"Kw8m5S2OhPs","uploaded":"2013-11-10T16:04:28.000Z","updated":"2014-02-18T17:59:36.000Z","uploader":"vkd-nAV91SLMCYNBKGJmsA","category":"People","title":"Beginners SEO Tutorial Course   Intro","description":"","thumbnail":
{"sqDefault":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Kw8m5S2OhPs/default.jpg","hqDefault":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Kw8m5S2OhPs/hqdefault.jpg"},"player":{"default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?
v=Kw8m5S2OhPs&feature=youtube_gdata_player","mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=Kw8m5S2OhPs"},"content":{"5":"https://www.youtube.com/v/Kw8m5S2OhPs?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata","1":"rtsp://r8---sn-4g57kues.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAn7hI4t5SYPKxMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp","6":"rtsp://r8---sn-
4g57kues.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAn7hI4t5SYPKxMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"},"duration":413,"aspectRatio":"widescreen","rating":5.0,"likeCount":"1","ratingCount":1,"viewCount":283,"favoriteCount":0,"commentCount":0,"accessControl":
{"comment":"allowed","commentVote":"allowed","videoRespond":"moderated","rate":"allowed","embed":"allowed","list":"allowed",
    "autoPlay":"allowed","syndicate":"allowed"}}}]}}';
 /*
  * If you want use the URL remove the comments
 */   
//$json_output = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL3n6kxxrIGdat31ZIf_7wlqtT3I20OqLL?v=2&alt=jsonc");

    $json = json_decode($json_output);
    $string = '';

    foreach($json->data->items[0]->video->thumbnail as $day) {


  $string .= $day . "|";
}

echo rtrim($string, '|');
```

Output:

```
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Kw8m5S2OhPs/default.jpg|https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Kw8m5S2OhPs/hqdefault.jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

try removing true from `json_decode()`

Comment: add "video" to foreach.

foreach($json->data->items->video->thumbnail as $day) 

I am making a mess in your code :)

Comment: the same the last problem no thing appear to me

Comment: when you var_dump($json); what do you see?

Comment: thank you for your care :) my problem is solved 
 and for your code i'm not using javascript in my project